# PytzUsageWarning: The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider

Tags: python, time, scheduler, pytz

I am writing a simple function that sends messages based on a schedule using AsyncIOScheduler.

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job, "cron", day_of_week="mon-fri", hour = "16")
scheduler.start()
```

It seems to work, but I always get the following message:

```
PytzUsageWarning: The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider. For more details on how to do so, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
PytzUsageWarning: The localize method is no longer necessary, as this time zone supports the fold attribute (PEP 495)
```

I am not familiar with time in python at all, so I am not really sure what this message is asking me to do. I visited the link provided in the message, but the explanation there is too complicated for me. As I understand, I have to migrate to using PEP495, but how exactly can I do just that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To set a PIP495 compatible timezone in APScheduler, set a parameter when instantiating the scheduler:

```py
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone="Europe/Berlin")
scheduler.add_job(job, "cron", day_of_week="mon-fri", hour = "16")
scheduler.start()
```

With `flask-APScheduler` (version 1.12.2), add the timezone to the configuration class:

```py
"""Basic Flask Example from flask-apscheduler examples, file jobs.py"""
from flask import Flask
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler


class Config:
    """App configuration."""
    JOBS = [
        {
            "id": "job1",
            "func": "jobs:job1",
            "args": (1, 2),
            "trigger": "interval",
            "seconds": 10,
        }
    ]
    SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED = True
    SCHEDULER_TIMEZONE = "Europe/Berlin"  # <========== add here


def job1(var_one, var_two):
    print(str(var_one) + " " + str(var_two))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config())

    scheduler = APScheduler()
    scheduler.init_app(app)
    scheduler.start()

    app.run()
```

Comment: for me I needed to add `timezone` to the IntervalTrigger, not the scheduler (I'm using BackgroundScheduler) to silence the warning

Comment: thanks a lot. using with pyrogram and works :)

Comment: Sure, that worked fine, I'll delete the previous ones

Comment: @Sergo055, if the answer solves your problem please accept it, so it is closed.

Comment: This won't solve the issue mentioned in the question, answer from @pavel-sapezhka solved the issue we had.

Comment: @Stefan, I tried the code and it solves it indeed, at least with the library versions I was using when I answered it.

Comment: @AlexPoca. Sorry, didnt check this page for a while. The answer did solve my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same warning message because of the zone.

What I did was:

```
import tzlocal

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone=str(tzlocal.get_localzone()))
```

With that local timezone I'm not getting the warning message anymore and it's running correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For now, you can't effectively suppress these warnings, because the problem comes from `apscheduler` itself.

In your particular case warning comes from [here](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/v3.8.1/apscheduler/util.py#L95)

```
if obj.zone == 'local':
```

The problem is `pytz` is considered deprecated in favor of `zoneinfo` module and its backports. So even if you set directly `timezone` argument as suggested before, you'll probably face the same warning from some other places until `apsheduler` would fix `pytz` usage for modern Python version.

But still, actually, **there is something that you could do**, but I'm not sure if such kind of fixes is acceptable for you.

`PytzUsageWarning` comes from `pytz_deprecation_shim` package which is the dependency of `tzlocal`. `tzlocal` is deeply integrated with `pytz`. As `apscheduler` has relatively relax dependency for `tzlocal`, you can install pretty old version of one, that hasn't such warning, but still acceptable for `apsscheduler` itself.

```
pip install tzlocal==2.1
```

But, please, pay attention *it could break other project dependencies*, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, the warnings did get suppressed after setting a timezone parameter when initiating the scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

I just changed to

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone=pytz.timezone('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'))
```

Comment: make sure to import 'pytz' ...otherwise, this works